# Profile save confirmation message uses light background even in dark mode

Tags: bug, profile-page, dark-mode

When saving changes made to the user profile in dark mode, the confirmation message uses a light background:

[image: "Your profile has been saved successfully." message has a light-green background.]

Answer (score 9):

You are correct there are no style difference between light or dark mode. The same light green, specifically `hsl(140,42%,95%)`, is used for both.

This is the class that is responsible:

```css
.val-success {
    background-color: hsl(140,42%,95%);
    border-color: hsl(140,40%,65%);
}
```

[image: Success element with a green checkmark, black text reading "Your profile has been saved successfully", on a light green background with a green border]

---

If we convert the static hsl values to custom properties instead

| hsl | Stacks Custom Properties |
| --- | --- |
| hsl(140,42%,95%) | --green-025 |
| hsl(140,40%,65%) | --green-300 |

Updating the CSS (including changing the font color of the text)

```css
.val-success {
    background-color: var(--green-025);
    border-color: var(--green-300);
}

.val-message p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: var(--theme-body-font-color);
}
```

This is what it would look like in dark mode (Light mode is [unchanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzqbL.png)):

[image: Success element with a green checkmark, white text "Your profile has been saved successfully", on a dark green background with a lighter green border]